# Sudo player command on gui click

Tags: java

I need this to teleport the player to another server, so how would I do so? I can do it two ways with implementing bungee but I rather not and my other option is to sudo the player so how would I do that?

```
        if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Multiplayer")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();
        //Here I need it to make the player run the command /server multiplayer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `player.performCommand(String command);`

Example:

```
Player player;
player.performCommand("server multiplayer"); //No slash
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `player.chat()`:

```
Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer("username");
//Or player = bukkit.getServer().getPlayer("username");
//Or player = (Player) sender;

player.chat("/server multiplayer"); //With slash
```

Comment: `player.chat("String")` isn't the recommended approach for commands! Use performCommand(String s) instead.

Comment: @Kerooker I would have suggested performCommand(), but you already did, so I used another method that does basically the same thing depending on the passed string. https://bukkit.org/threads/make-a-player-execute-a-command.41765/#post-751712

Comment: Furthermore Bukkit.getPlayerExact("username") is the new recomended method.

Answer (score 0):

Solved if used:

```
        if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains("Multiplayer")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();
        Player targetPlayer = Bukkit.getPlayer(e.getWhoClicked().getName());
        targetPlayer.performCommand("server multiplayer");
```